# sql query getting duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I am using below query.

```
Create proc [dbo].[usp_getPropertyByWord]  
(@Description nvarchar(200))  
as  

set @Description=replace(@Description,'   ',' ')  
set @Description=replace(@Description,'  ',' ') 

create table #temp(name varchar(100)) 
insert into #temp valueS(@Description)
insert into #temp 
SELECT word FROM dbo.splitStringChars(@Description,' ',',')
delete #temp where name in('',' ',',')

create table #temp1(property_id int,property_number nvarchar(15),name nvarchar(500),short_desciption nvarchar(2000),description nvarchar(4000),address1 nvarchar(200),address2 nvarchar(200),city nvarchar(50),locality nvarchar(100),zip nvarchar(8)) 
insert into #temp1(property_id,property_number,name ,short_desciption,description,address1,address2,city,locality,zip)
SELECT distinct(p.property_id),p.property_number,p.name,p.short_description,p.description,ta.address1,ta.address2,
tc.city_name,cl.City_Locality_Name,ta.zip
FROM tbl_property p  
INNER JOIN 
tbl_PropertyAddress ta on ta.property_id=p.property_id
inner join tbl_City tc on ta.city=tc.city_id
inner join  tbl_City_Locality cl on cl.City_id=tc.city_id
inner join
(SELECT distinct(name) FROM #temp) B  
ON (p.name=@Description or p.name LIKE '%' + B.name + '%' or p.short_description like '%' + B.name + '%' or p.description like '%' + B.name + '%'
or ta.address1 LIKE '%' + B.name + '%' or ta.address2 LIKE '%' + B.name + '%' or tc.City_Name LIKE '%' + B.name + '%')  
where  NOT EXISTS(select t.* from #temp1 t where t.property_id=p.property_id and t.property_number=p.property_number and t.name=p.name and t.short_desciption=p.short_description and t.description=p.description and t.address1=ta.address1 and t.address2=ta.address2 and t.city=tc.City_Name and t.locality=cl.City_Locality_Name and t.zip=ta.zip)


  delete  #temp
  select  *  from #temp1
GO
```

If i give **" 'hyderbad hyd,hgf , hyds  '"** for  @Description  i getting 16000 records,but i have only 130 records in my table.

I am getting values from splitStringChars function

```
hyderbad     
hyd    
hgf    
hyds
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: Sounds like a bad JOIN is causing a many-to-many relationship... Have you tried commenting out some of the complexity to determine which join is causing you problem?

Comment: Even using distinct may not return only a single row if one of the column values from the joins differ.  Follow Kevin's advice and remove the complexity until you find when you stop getting multiples.  That should help you figure out which table and column is causing the multiple records.

Comment: Then tell me how to use join i need to check in all these columns

Comment: My question is clear but whey they give negative .If join are many to many please tell me how to reduce...

Comment: It's basic debugging technique : start with the "inner-most" query and make sure it returns the right data. Then, one by one, add additional tables via JOIN and see *where* you suddenly get duplicates, and then you need to use your brain to understand *why* you are getting duplicates and fix it. We cannot really do this work for you - we don't have your database at hand to do the testing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know TSQL?

```
Create proc [dbo].[usp_getPropertyByWord]  
(@Description nvarchar(200))  
as  

set @Description=replace(@Description,'   ',' ')  
set @Description=replace(@Description,'  ',' ') 

create table #temp(name varchar(100)) 
insert into #temp valueS(@Description)
insert into #temp 
SELECT word FROM dbo.splitStringChars(@Description,' ',',')
delete #temp where name in('',' ',',')


SELECT p.property_id,p.property_number,p.name,p.short_description,p.description
-- ,ta.address1,ta.address2,tc.city_name,cl.City_Locality_Name,ta.zip
FROM tbl_property p  
-- INNER JOIN 
--tbl_PropertyAddress ta on ta.property_id=p.property_id
--inner join tbl_City tc on ta.city=tc.city_id
--inner join  tbl_City_Locality cl on cl.City_id=tc.city_id
inner join
(SELECT distinct(name) FROM #temp) B  
ON (p.name=@Description or p.name LIKE '%' + B.name + '%' or p.short_description like '%' + B.name + '%' or p.description like '%' + B.name + '%'
-- or ta.address1 LIKE '%' + B.name + '%' or ta.address2 LIKE '%' + B.name + '%' 
-- or tc.City_Name LIKE '%' + B.name + '%'
)  
where  NOT EXISTS(select t.* from #temp1 t where t.property_id=p.property_id and t.property_number=p.property_number and t.name=p.name and t.short_desciption=p.short_description and t.description=p.description 
-- and t.address1=ta.address1 and t.address2=ta.address2 and t.city=tc.City_Name and t.locality=cl.City_Locality_Name and t.zip=ta.zip
)
```